# How to sort a map containing a map of values

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have the data structure as below:

```
class SKUPriceVO {
    String skuId;
    Map<String, PriceVo> priceMap;
}

class PriceVo {
    String type;
    String skuId;
    double price;
}
```

The map I need to sort is:
`Map<String, SKUPriceVo>` myMap in the way the that its sorted according to the price in PriceVo object ie> myMap should have the SKUPriceVo arranged in ascending or descending order based on the price in PriceVo.

Comment: What does it mean to "sort a map"?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly sort a hashmap. What you need to do is move your map data to list and sort that list based on the price.

```
List<Map.Entry<Integer, PriceVo >> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, PriceVo >>(map.entrySet());

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, PriceVo >>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, PriceVo > price1,
                           Map.Entry<Integer, PriceVo > price2) {
            return price1.getValue().price.compareTo(price2.getValue().price);
        }
    }
);
```

You can even use a Treemap and directly pass a Comparator to it and sort, so there will be no need to copy the data in other list.

Comment: But, that will just sort the priceMap which is in SKUPriceVo object. Then how do we sort the outer map too which is "myMap" based on the PriceVo prices?

Comment: In the same way as you sorted priceMap.